# Continuity equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow

When a fluid molecule suffers decrease in area whether smoothly or sharply its velocity vector strikes the wall but both in case of elastic and inelastic collision it looses/changes its velocity direction and magnitude. Then how its velocity increases when it has passed through the orifice/smaller area which is inferred by using the continuity equation $A_1 v_1 = A_2 v_2$.

Comment: Do you think that the continuity equation refers to a single molecule?  Irrespective of the conservation of momentum and energy, do you think that mass is conserved?

Comment: Continuity equation talks about the flux passing through an area. So to visualize I take an area $A_1$ and consider vector field(arrows) passing through it in a single direction. Then I take an area $A_2$ again with the same vector field but now densely filled than its prior one considering $A1 > A2$.

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence in your comment.

Comment: Is continuity equation derived by probability theory?

Comment: No.  It is a mathematical expression based on conservation of mass.

Comment: Then please explain what do you meant by the first comment.

Comment: @VisheshMangla, you are "over-thinking" this problem.  The continuity equation is based solely on conservation of mass, and says nothing about velocity vectors, elastic or inelastic collisions, streamlines, etc.

Comment: Well, actually this doubt didn't arise me in the fluid mechanics class but rather a heat transfer one. The teacher was telling how to find out the velocity in a staggered arrangement [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=heat+transfer+tube+plate+staggered&client=firefox-b-d&channel=crow2&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=q5bmsHZZH60l0M%253A%252CLx48guN60hoj_M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kSWTYnBto-QEmNmkWtyMjog_1UY0g&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW2cTP3pLoAhV4xzgGHQdoAuAQ9QEwAHoECAoQHg#imgrc=q5bmsHZZH60l0M:). I considered inlet velocity as $U_{\infty}$.

Comment: and that velocity in the gaps to be  $U_{\infty} cos(\theta)$. She said it's done by conservation of mass and not this way. I had been doing this for so many years. $cos(\theta) $ can be easily found out by geometry.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases the pressure is much lower beyond an orifice.  The molecules are being pushed from behind.  With a decrease in area, again where the velocity is higher, the pressure is lower.

Comment: That is true and can be considered.

Answer (score 0):

I think an answer lies in the assumption that velocity of a particle is always along the streamline and we usually we talk about steady state flow in which the streamline has already been bent in that direction of the flow. The $\nabla \psi$ where $\psi$ is the stream function is the $\vec{V}$ or velocity vector. If you consider transition state flow it would definately suffer momentum loss and there would be a mass reflux and continuity equation wouldn't be valid.